# Manually entering attribute information for each point in QGIS edit session?

Tags: qgis, editing

I am new to QGIS and am editing an existing point shapefile that has 5 TYPE classifications. In ARCMap I can click on a symbolized TYPE point and the new digitized point will have the same attributes. In QGIS it seems that each newly added point in the file requires a manually attribute information.

Is there a tool or set-up that mimics the ease of editing in ArcMap?

Comment: can you explain more this ArcGIS workflow you're describing?

Comment: mapBaker In ArcMap I have a .shp point file that identifies 5 categories of dwelling units

Comment: mapBaker I am trying to edit an existing, large, point .shp that has an attribute field called TYPE. This symbology consists of features that identify Types of dwellings in Kenya's Samburu landscape. I want to be able to add a point and have it retain the attributes that are existing in the .shp that is being edited.

Comment: Oh so are you talking about 'subtypes' and 'domains'?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not aware of a feature to completely mimic this.  However, the ["attribute painter"](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/attributePainter/) plugin allows you to automatically 'paint' attributes from a specified feature onto selected features.  This might be a possible workaround?

Comment: Jakob this is exactly what I was looking for, particularly the first screenshot related to new geometries. I will try it out today.  Thankyou very much

Answer (score 3):

In the settings you can reuse last entered attribute values. This only works for adding new geometries.

[image]

Another way for existing data would be to use the field calculator updating selected features with a given value.

Another way again will be to change the field edit widget to unique values, for a column where you need to select a value from a list of existing values.
[image]